# Form submit event in a view

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

I have a form inside a View. How and where can I handle the form submit event? Also where can I write the code for handling events on elements present in this form. I tried handling it at:

```
//Instantiating a view with a template name signup
var signup = Ember.View.create({
templateName: "signup",
name: 'Sign Up',
click: function()
{
alert('click triggered from signup template');
},
submit: function()
{
alert('submit triggered');
},
signup: function()
{
alert('signup triggered');
}
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="signup">
<form class="form-horizontal"  {{action "signup" on="submit"}}>
<br/>
<div  align="center" >
<table class="table-hover>
<tr>
    <td>
    <label>First Name</label>
    </td>

    <td>
    {{input value=firstName class="controls" type="text"}}
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    </td>

    <td>
    {{input value=lastName class="controls" type="text"}}
    </td>
</tr>

<button class="btn  btn-primary " type="submit" >Register</button>
</div>
</form>
</script>
```

When I click anywhere on the button, only click event is triggered. How do I get access to the submit event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer includes, two solutions. The first being a method using views correctly. The second solution uses an Ember Component, which I think is closer to what you were looking to do.

---

## Ember View Method:

I have created a [working demo here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ItEZiDO/1/edit), for you to look at.

The are a few things you need to do:

### Your template code:

You need to be careful that you create clean and valid code. You have not closed the class name on your `<table>` tag nor have you included the closing `</table>` tag. This is the cleaned up template:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" {{action "signup" on="submit"}}>
    <br/>
    <div align="center">
        <table class="table-hover">
            <tr>
                <td><label>First Name</label></td>
                <td>{{input value=firstName class="controls" type="text"}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Last Name</label></td>
                <td>{{input value=lastName class="controls" type="text"}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

### Using your view:

You cannot add actions to a view like that. Actions of the view must be handled either on the `Route` or the `Controller`. [See here](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/) for examples on how to use actions with a view.

Essentially, your action handler would be trying to pass the action to the controller, or route that was including your view. Notice in my demo, that the `IndexRoute` has the model, and the action to take, and that the index template referenced the view:

```
{{view App.SignUpForm}}
```

---

## Ember Component Method:

If you want to keep the action inside your *view*, then you need to use a component. [See this demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UqAJitO/1/edit), for use as a component.

```
App.SignUpFormComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  templateName: "signup",
  actions: {
    signup: function(){
      alert("SignUp Clicked");
    }
  }
});
```

It's usage is slightly different, but now the action is self contained, and does not need to be included in the `Route` or `Controller` which is perhaps more what you were looking for.

To use it you can do:

```
{{sign-up-form data=this}}
```

Your model data is now accessible in the component by doing `data.firstName` and `data.lastName`, so the template is slightly modified too. You can see this in the HTML section of the JSBin demo I included.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, How long did it take to frame this answer in such a good way?

Comment: @RajeshPaul You mean format my answer this way? Or to come up with the overall solution? About 30 minutes overall. If you think it's useful don't forget to upvote.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for putting in so much effort . I have tried the first approach.Actually I am trying to add the form to a modal. The modal is also a view itself. I still can't catch the events from the form anywhere. Your solution works for the case you have demonstrated so I will mark it as an accepted answer.